# Recyclerview gridlayoutmanager

Tags: android, recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

Есть `RecyclerView` с `GridLayoutManager`, но он ставит одинаковую ширину у всех элементов. Как сделать разную ширину?

Comment: можете попробовать вот этот: https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout/blob/master/libraries/layouts/src/main/java/org/apmem/tools/layouts/FlowLayoutManager.java

Comment: Спасибо, попробую написать свой.

Comment: А тот, что я дал не подошел?

Comment: Слишком много лишнего нужно добавить